# Left join instead of inner join when using entity splitting

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

As addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6263329/289246) question, I took [Ladislav Mrnka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263329/two-tables-considered-as-one/6263497#6263497).

The problem is that some of the entries of Table1 doesn't show up. So I used the sql server profiler and see that the query executed used `INNER JOIN` where I need to do `LEFT JOIN`.

In Table1 I have data the dosen't have match in Table2 and this data must appear.

How can I solve this?

Comment: take a look to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323830/linq-getteing-a-list-from-another-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case you cannot use Entity Splitting as asked in your former question. Entity splitting demands that both parts of the mapped entity exists and because of that it uses inner join. Either modify your database to have both parts for each entity or remove entity splitting and use `Table1` and `Table2` directly to have control over created query.

Answer (score 2):

the key is DefaultIfEmpty()

```
var query =
from t1 in Table1
join t2 in Table2
on t1 equals t2 into NewTable
from result in NewTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
select (Your select)
```

Comment: To save the OP some frustration, I already told him about `DefaultIfEmpty()` and it wasn't what he was looking for so I deleted my answer.